# Does TLS v1.2 curl call require any upgrade in server certificates

Tags: php, ssl, curl, tls1.2, authorize.net

I have a couple of websites that use Authorize.NET payment. Since they have upgraded to only support TLS 1.2, one of my websites do not work.

I updated the integration to work with TLS v1.2 but it is not validating cards anymore.

I am using php curl with this particular change:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
```

where value of the define is:

```
define('CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2',   6);
```

The question is that is there some server certificate upgrade also required to support the calls to Authorize.NET ?

Comment: Did you get it working yet? :)

Answer (score 0):

TLS 1.2 should work with all certificates which are still practically relevant and worked with older versions of TLS. It might not work with certificates having only a MD5 signature but these certificates are long obsolete and should not be in use for years now, i.e. not practically relevant.
The problem you have is therefore most likely not the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing your environment information and error details would be helpful in finding the cause. Either way, you must make sure your TLS 1.2 is working or not. You can try testing with [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/tls-http-upgrade)'s [TLS test](https://tlstest.paypal.com) or [How's My SSL](https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check).

If that didn't go well, first check your OpenSSL and cURL versions. TLS 1.2 is supported since [OpenSSL 1.0.1](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x31) and [cURL 7.34](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--tlsv12). You can find your OpenSSL version by running command `openssl_version` and `php --ri curl` to find your cURL version. Do note that PHP's cURL uses it's own OpenSSL library, so you might have different versions than your OpenSSL installed on your system.
If your versions are outdated, you can update by running `yum update openssl` for OpenSSL and `yum update curl libcurl` for cURL. Remember to restart your web server after updating.
You may also need to update your [CA certificates to the latest (extracted from Mozilla)](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem). Simply download it, place it somewhere or replace your current `cacert.perm`, add the path to your certificate to `openssl.cafile` and `curl.cainfo` in your `php.ini`, and then try again.

[More about TLS 1.2 requirement for PHP](https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update#php).